# Promise.All returning empty

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have few api call requests which i am trying to create promises and then execute all using `Promise.all` but, its giving empty value instead of array. Below is my code.

```js
function getUser(arrUser) {
  var student = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (arrUser.length > 0) {
      var promises = arrUseridRequest.map(userRequeset => {
        return getRequest(userRequeset).then(result => {
          student.push(JSON.parse(result.body).result[0].Name);
          console.log(student); //This is giving right details.
        }).catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });

      Promise.all(promises).then(StuName => {
        resolve(StuName.join());
      })
    }
  });
}
```

and this is how i am trying to get the values at once:

```js
getUser('123').then(student => {
  console.log(Student) //Coming as empty
});
```

`getRequest` is my api call nodeJs request module. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You are using promises as a fancy callback system. Promise represents a value itself. So you need to create an array of promises returning something, not populating some external array. Then use Promise.all to produce final result.

Comment: `console.log(Student)` Is this a typo? Shouldn’t this be `student` with small `s`?

Comment: not sure you need to the student array to store the results or even the `new Promise` bit.  I think... nm @YuryTarabanko just replied what I was going to get to.

Comment: Where is `arrUser` parameter used? What is `arrUseridRequest`?

Comment: Also you rarely need to use `Promise` constructor directly. Definitely not in the example you have. `Promise.all` creates one for you.

Comment: many issues with the code sample.  My recommendation is to limit  what you are trying to do and functionality from a basis of it working... e.g. get it working for jsut one record, not an array.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Could you please help me how that can be done?

Comment: `function getUsers(users) { return Promise.all( users.map(user => /* create a promise returning what you need for each user*/)}` can't write anything more useful because you have some random variables popping here and there in your code snippet.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: `return getRequest(userRequeset).then(result => {` <--- this then returns nothing, you just push to an array.

Comment: @epascarello It still returns a promise from the `map` callback

Answer (score 2):

All your `promises` fulfill with the value `undefined` since you're just logging the student names, but not `return`ing them from the `then` callback. As you seem to be doing only a single request, the array will be `[undefined]`, which is joined into the empty string.

Also avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it):

```
function getUsers(arrUser) {
  const promises = arrUser.map(userId => {
    return getRequest(userId).then(result => {
      const students = JSON.parse(result.body).result;
      return students[0].Name;
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
getUsers(['123']).then(studentNames => {
  console.log(studentNames);
  console.log(studentNames.join());
}).catch(console.error);
```